# cant install bcompiler pecl extension

Tags: php, pecl, bcompiler

I have googled this until I am blue in the face - no matter what I try I can't seem to get bcompiler to install.

I am running xampp 1.8.1 on windows

```
# pecl install bcompiler
downloading bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz (57,347 bytes)
..............done: 57,347 bytes
11 source files, building
ERROR: The DSP bcompiler.dsp does not exist.
```

I have also tried downloading the extension source and building it although this is a little out of my depth - I then receive the error that the output from msdev is not understood.

I have also tried going back a few versions of xampp and not having any luck, but I really want this running on php 5.4

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you can do the following steps for installing the bcompiler on linux

```
root@linux# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz

root@linux# tar -xvf bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz

root@linux# cd bcompiler-1.0.2

root@linux# phpize

root@linux# ./configure

root@linux# make

root@linux# make install

root@linux# make test
```

and finally you have to create an ini file , `bcompiler.ini` inside

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
```

and add this line

```
extension=bcompiler.so
```

and finally restart your webserver

will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Simply Download file from http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler

Action :- Just make sure, you read output, At one point it will tell you where bcompiler.so file has been save.

```
root@linux# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz
root@linux# tar -xvf bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz
root@linux# cd bcompiler-1.0.2
root@linux# phpize
root@linux# ./configure
root@linux# make
root@linux# make install
root@linux# make test
```

If nothing has gone wrong than bcompiler.so file must have been placed to 'ext' directory..

Now Start using your bcompiler if everything was OK :)